# Graphql: Find value in array field of object

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, graphql-js

I want to filter list value ['500', '600'] in tags field.
Tags field is []varchar.

Like in mongodb: `{tags: {$in: ['500', '600']}}`

I try in graphql. but its not working

```
  questions(where: {tags: {_in: ["500ae"]}}) {
    id
  }
}
```

Result error:

```
{
 "errors": [
   {
     "extensions": {
       "path": "$",
       "code": "constraint-error"
     },
     "message": "type \"_varchar[]\" does not exist"
   }
 ]
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD171.png)

Comment: Please show us the backend code that resolves the `questions` field. We can't tell you anything from the information you provided so far, except that your backend throws an error.

Comment: @Bergi hello bergi, first. i'm so sorry because my english not good. and what do you want to see? it

Comment: All the relevant code for resolving that query which could throw `constraint-error`s.

Comment: Please read  the help section [ask]. Using that as a template for your question tends to get you better answers.